# Binary search as a template function

Tags: c++

I feel like I am very close but I cannot seem to get it. Thanks for any help!

```
#include<iostream>
#include<list>
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>
#include<iterator>

template<typename iterator>
iterator binarySearch(iterator begin, iterator end, int target){
    iterator start = begin;
    iterator stop = end;
    while( start != stop){
            int distance = std::distance(start,stop);
            iterator middle = begin;
            std::advance(middle, distance/2);
            if(*middle == target){
                    return middle;
            }
            else if(*middle < target){
                    start = std::advance(middle,1);
            }
            else{
                    stop = middle;
            }
    }
    return end;
}    
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::vector<int> v = {1,2,5,7,9,13,15,18};
    std::list<int> l = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    std::vector<int>::iterator a = binarySearch(v.begin(),v.end(), 7);
    std::list<int>::iterator b = binarySearch(l.begin(),l.end(), 7);
    std::cout<<"7 is the "<<(*a)<<"th position in the vector.\n";
    std::cout<<"7 is the "<<(*b)<<"th position in the list.\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Below is the error I am getting:

```
Lab8.cpp: In instantiation of ‘iterator binarySearch(iterator, iterator, int) [with iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int>]’:
Lab8.cpp:35:66:   required from here
Lab8.cpp:24:10: error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >’ and ‘void’)
    start = std::advance(middle,1);
          ^
Lab8.cpp:24:10: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_algobase.h:67:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/iostream:39,
                 from Lab8.cpp:6:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_iterator.h:709:11: note: __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >& __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >::operator=(const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >&)
     class __normal_iterator
           ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_iterator.h:709:11: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘void’ to ‘const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >&’
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_iterator.h:709:11: note: __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >& __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >::operator=(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >&&)
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_iterator.h:709:11: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘void’ to ‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >&&’
Lab8.cpp: In instantiation of ‘iterator binarySearch(iterator, iterator, int) [with iterator = std::_List_iterator<int>]’:
Lab8.cpp:36:64:   required from here
Lab8.cpp:24:10: error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::_List_iterator<int>’ and ‘void’)
    start = std::advance(middle,1);
          ^
Lab8.cpp:24:10: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/list:63:0,
                 from Lab8.cpp:7:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_list.h:125:12: note: std::_List_iterator<int>& std::_List_iterator<int>::operator=(const std::_List_iterator<int>&)
     struct _List_iterator
            ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_list.h:125:12: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘void’ to ‘const std::_List_iterator<int>&’
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_list.h:125:12: note: std::_List_iterator<int>& std::_List_iterator<int>::operator=(std::_List_iterator<int>&&)
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_list.h:125:12: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘void’ to ‘std::_List_iterator<int>&&’
```

Comment: `std::advance` doesn't return iterator.

Comment: _"This is the error ... sorry, could post a picture yet as I am new"_ You put error messages here verbatim as text. _"Friend suggested this website so I thought I'd ask. "_ Kick their ass! Kick them hard!

Comment: To be precise, `start = std::advance(middle, 1);` is the problem.

Comment: IMO, this shouldn't be down voted. I understand that he should be analysing the compilation errors before posting here. But, down voting discourages the newbies.

Comment: It was easy to miss that error messages had been included at all, if you assumed the text box listing code was only code and didn't scroll down far enough.  I've moved the error into its own code section.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you used `std::advance` instead of `std::next`. The former returns `void`, whereas the latter returns an incremented iterator.

So the line

```
start = std::advance(middle,1);
```

should be

```
start = std::next(middle);
```

The problem is that even with that modification, your code goes into an infinite loop (but at least compiles, which is a first step). Use a debugger to see what's wrong.

Comment: Thank you! Figured it out by simplifying my template function. Also had to change what I was printing out to the distance between the beginning of the vector/list I was using and the location of the found value.